# get table records through another table with Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have three tables and two pivot tables!

**artists**

* id (primary)
...

**music_artists**

* id (primary)

* music_id (foreignKey)

* artist_id (foreignKey)

**musics**

 id (primary)

 ...

**album_musics**

  id (primary)

 music_id (foreign key)

 album_id (foreign key)

...

***albums***

 id (primary)

 ...

my question is how can I access to artists of an album with laravel **eloquent**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with support for `BelongsToMany`: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```
class Album extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function artists() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            Artist::class,
            ['album_musics', Music::class, 'music_artists']
        );
    }
}
```